# Simplistic parallel grid search in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, parallel-processing

<sub>Ok, full disclosure, I'm not doing a grid search but the **minimum example** I could find for what I'm about to ask could (with a grain of salt) be reduced to a grid search (in case you're wondering why I'm not mentioning numpy and friends).</sub>

---

I'm doing a grid search in Python where one axis is discrete and the other one continuous, but for simplicity, let's say I have the following:

```
x_axis = ['linear', 'quadratic', 'cubic']
y_axis = range(1, 100) # simplification
```

The evaluation of my function depends on both axes and an intermediate log structure, so in an effort to have no global data I'm defining my function as a **closure**:

```
def get_function(xval, *args): 
    """ creates the closure that encapsulates thread local data 
    """
    log = { } # initialization depends on args
    def fun(yval): 
    """ evaluation dedicated to single x_axis value 
    """
        if yval in log: 
            # in a proper grid search I wouldn't check twice
            # but this is just to show that log  is used and 
            # ammended inside fun()
        else: 
            log[yval] = 0

        return very_time_consuming_fun(xval, yval, log)
```

So the script uses this set up to run a grid search:

```
def func_eval(fun): 
    for yval in y_axis: 
        fun(yval)

# the loop I want to parallelize    
for xval in x_axis: 
    fun = get_function(xval, args) # args are computed based on xval
    func_eval(fun)                 # can I do result = func_eval(fun) ?
```

The things I want to ask are:

- Am I correct in assuming that `log` works with a **different instance** for each `x_axis` value?
- What is the **best way to parallelize the last `for` loop?** (If synchronization is needed for the `log` instances please elaborate). Again, I only want the evaluation of each `x_axis` value to its thread / core / you name it (best practices are welcomed)
- Is there a way to **get results out for each `func_eval`** i.e. could it still be parallelized, if I had the following:

  ```
  out = func_eval(fun)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I hate the silence ...

This is what I'm doing for now (so at least I'll get downvoted if it ain't right)

```
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
funcs = [get_function(xval, args) for x in x_axis]
outputs = pool.map(func_eval, funcs)
```

this should be good enough according but I get the following error:

> PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.function failed